# Get URL of 'calling endpoint', from where another endpoint got requested - Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Assume I have three routes as below:

```
@app.route('/route_one')
def route_one():
    return redirect(url_for(target_route))

@app.route('/route_two')
def route_two():
    return redirect(url_for(target_route))

@app.route('/target_route')
def target_route():
    print('I got called by ......')
```

Is there a default way, to determine within target_route, from where it got called, so either by route_one or route_two?

I am aware that there are workarounds, like passing the 'calling' endpoint as arugment to the target_route, but my question is if there is a default / built-in functionality to achieve this within Flask and its request handler.